Hardy-Littlewood maximal function
I am studying measure and integration theory following Stein and Shakarchi. The Hardy-Littlewood maximal function is introduced for an integrable function f as $f^*(x)=\text{sup}_{x\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B |f(y)|dy$ with the supremum taken over all balls containing $x$. They go on to prove
$m(\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:f^*(x)>\alpha\})\le \frac{A}{\alpha}\int_\mathbb{R^d}|f(x)|dx$ where $\alpha>0$, $A=3^d$ and comment: The effect of the above result is broadly speaking that $f^*$ is not much larger that $|f|$.
Q: Why can the result be interpreted like this?  General discussion of the maximal function is also very welcome.
